# Can I pull out a single cell with query in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to find a way to (I think) get a single cell out as part of a query that also returns columns, I don't know if it's even possible. Brief explanation - every quarter we get v. detailed audit reports in via google sheets in 6 spreadsheets of between 20-45 case files each, each with their own separate tab/sheet within that. I've managed to use query to pull out and collate the major issues from all of them in a new sheet for analysis using

=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(A3,"Case File 1!F18:M");IMPORTRANGE(A3,"Case File 2!F18:M");IMPORTRANGE(A3,"Case File 3!F18:M")},"Select Col1,Col4,Col7 where Col4 contains 'concern'")

This gives me a neat list of all the concern point narratives against the specific criteria they come under, to do funky things with, but what I haven't managed to do is actually get anything that says 'these concern points are from Case File 1' or similar. There could be 0, 1, 5 concern points, so I never know how many rows it's going to return. Is there an easy way to go 'select this one cell (with the organisation name on) as well as the concern bits and stick the name next to all of them? I doubt it, but any ideas welcome, I don't want to have to run the queries separately and collate them later. Can't attach a copy of the sheets unfortunately, it's all confidential info. I've tried adding Col3 to the mix, which is the one with the name on (and some other extraneous info that looks messy, but ah well) but this only returns the name bit for the first sheet on the top - I haven't got the hang of headers so that might be why?
Cheers, sorry for the length, first question and I'm not sure what you need to know.
Meg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=arrayformula(
query({
query({iferror(IMPORTRANGE(A3,"Case File 1!F18:F")/0,"Case File 1"),IMPORTRANGE(A3,"Case File 1!F18:M")},"where Col5 contains 'concern'",0);
query({iferror(IMPORTRANGE(A3,"Case File 1!F18:F")/0,"Case File 2"),IMPORTRANGE(A3,"Case File 2!F18:M")},"where Col5 contains 'concern'",0);
query({iferror(IMPORTRANGE(A3,"Case File 1!F18:F")/0,"Case File 3"),IMPORTRANGE(A3,"Case File 3!F18:M")},"where Col5 contains 'concern'",0)
},"select Col1,Col2,Col5,Col8",0)
)
```

This option places the text column at the end (and just one query):

```
=arrayformula(
    query({
    IMPORTRANGE(A3,"Case File 1!F18:M"),iferror(IMPORTRANGE(A3,"Case File 1!F18:F")/0,"Case File 1");
    IMPORTRANGE(A3,"Case File 2!F18:M"),iferror(IMPORTRANGE(A3,"Case File 2!F18:F")/0,"Case File 2");
    IMPORTRANGE(A3,"Case File 3!F18:M"),iferror(IMPORTRANGE(A3,"Case File 3!F18:F")/0,"Case File 3")
    },"select Col1,Col4,Col7,Col9 where Col4 contains 'concern' ",0))
```

[image]

Comment: That's fantastic, that worked, thank you! Is that pointing it at the sheet name somehow? Is there a way to wrap the whole thing in an iferror instead of each query? I need to replicate it for up to 45 case files, but then if I only have to spend one afternoon copy pasting into the formula bar it's still better than looking them all up. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Also I can see that the column numbers have moved on one, I'm not 100% why but I'm guessing we've somehow added a virtual sheet name column on the front?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thank you :) Yes, the sheet URL is in A3, Column numbers moved on is absolutely fine, no worries there, just keeping a bit of a log of stuff I've learned for future reference, and I will do that, cheers!

Comment: Come up against another issue, sorry. The formula still works fine on its own, but then when I extend it to cover case files up to 45, it gives me an array literal error. I'm pretty certain this is because some of those case files don't have any concern points, so the columns are mismatched sizes and won't pull across. I know I can fix that if it's occuring in a basic query formula on its own with an iferror and then add in three fake columns with "","","" but I have no idea if that's possible with this formula given it's already using an iferror.  Any ideas welcome! Cheers.

Comment: Did you try the formula at the bottom of the solution? The one with just the single query. I've tried it on 3 sheets, 1 of which doesn't have any 'concern' values and it works fine. See https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iW-Z80DocCUPMkGmXE4GcsV1dDUxYziCGw5b5syFauM/copy

Comment: That's great, that worked, cheers! I didn't realise the formula was so different at the end as well, just went with the first one as it worked. Building it up gradually now to see if the amount of files is a problem but I think you cracked it :D